# Change statusbar Winterboard

Tags: iphone, ios, themes, jailbreak, statusbar

I'm creating a new Winterboard theme,
and i wanted to change the status bar on the iPhone…
Is this possible using Winterboard ?
And.. How?

Thanks
Evert de Spiegeleer

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can, but it's a hack (and apple def. has another, better way of doing it that we don't have access to):
Set the status bar to black translucent and have a (sub)view with your wanted color as backgroundcolor directly behind it. That way you can get the effect of a different color, even with a gradient.
the frame for that would be `CGRectMake(0,0,320,20)`

Comment: Thanks, but i already tough that, actually my question should be:  How do i make it black in Winterboard ? Sry...